# Plotting a dataset with two dependent Y axes using Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

Basically I want to plot the graph below using a similar dataset, [one may note that each line is related with both y1 and y2 axes at the same time.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBDlD.png) I have a csv file with three columns, one for x and the others for y1 and y2.
How should I plot this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If `y1 = a y2 +b`, you simply need to set the `y2range` appropriately and ask for it to be shown.

```
set yrange [0:1]
set y2range [0:10]
set y2tics
plot [0:1] x
```